# Cannot figure out why I am getting incompatible types

Tags: java

I am having trouble with an incompatible types error while trying to write a method based off these instructions: "a method that takes an int parameter and displays on the screen the details (name,year of birth etc.) of the Cat stored at that index position. This method must ensure that the parameter is a valid index position and display an error message if it is not."  (there are two classed in the program which use each other). I have commented where I am getting the error below. I would appreciate some assistance. Thanks.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Cattery
{
// instance variables - replace the example below with your own
private ArrayList <Cat> cats;
private String businessName;

/**
 * Constructor for objects of class Cattery
 */
public Cattery(String NewBusinessName)
{
    cats = new ArrayList <Cat>();
    NewBusinessName = businessName;
}

public void addCat(Cat newCat){

    cats.add(newCat);
}

public void indexDisplay(int index) {
    if((index >= 0) && (index <= cats.size()-1)) {
        index = cats.get(index);                       //incompatible types?
        System.out.println(index);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid index position!");
    }
 }

 public void removeCat(int indexremove){
     if((indexremove >= 0) && (indexremove <= cats.size()-1)) {
         cats.remove(indexremove);
        }
    else{
        System.out.println("Invalid index position!");
    }
  }

 public void displayNames(){
   System.out.println("The current guests in Puss in Boots Cattery:");
   for(Cat catNames : cats ){
       System.out.println(catNames.getName());

 }
 }
 }
```

Comment: you add `Cat` to the list using `cats.add(newCat);` you can't expect to get something else with `cats.get(index);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have defined cats like this:

```
 cats = new ArrayList <Cat>();
```

This will return a cat at position `index`:

```
cats.get(index);
```

But you have defined index as an int and are assignign a cat to it:

```
 index = cats.get(index);
```

The correct way to get an item from the list is:

```
Cat cat = cats.get(index);
```

To print the name of the retrieved cat simply run:

```
System.out.println(cat.getName());
```

Answer (score 2):

problem in this statement :

```
index = cats.get(index);
```

cats.get(index) returns a cat object. where as index is of a int type. cat object cannot be assigned to int type variable. Hence it shows Types Incompatible.

One solution is to do this:

```
Cat cat = cats.get(index);
```

and to print the cat that is returned by the above statement, you can override [toString()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29) in Cat class

do the following :

```
public String toString()
{
    return "cat name: " + this.getName();
}
```

to print the information of the Cat in your Cattery class use the below statement

```
System.out.println(cat);
```

Answer (score 1):

`cats.get()` returns `Cat`, and you're trying to assign the result to an `int`:

```
    index = cats.get(index);                       //incompatible types?
```

It's unclear what the purpose of the function is, but you can store the result of `cats.get()` like so:

```
    Cat cat = cats.get(index);
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work. When I call the method it just displays the literal parameter input, instead of displaying information of the cat.

Comment: @JoshuaBaker: Are you printing `index` or `cat`?

Comment: I tried both. When I print index I get the literal parameter input. When I type in cat, when calling the method is display something wierd like "Cat@68c6fc84"

Comment: @Joshua Baker its the virtual address of the Cat in the cats list.

Comment: @Joshua Baker to print the information of the cat, first overide the toString() in the Cat class and do System.out.println(cat);

Comment: what I am trying to do is print out information such as the name of the cat. In the other class I have a getName method. How would I call this to print out correctly, from the correct index location. I tried System.out.println(cats.get(index)); but didnt work

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so in this line:

```
index = cats.get(index);
```

What are you *expecting* `cats.get(index)` to return? `cats` is of type `ArrayList<Cat>` - so you should find the documentation for [`ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), then navigate to the [`get`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29) method, and see that it's declared like this:

```
public E get(int index)
```

So in an `ArrayList<Cat>`, the `get` method will return `Cat`.

So you want:

```
Cat cat = cats.get(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
 index = cats.get(index);
```

will return the Cat item it will not return the int value
here u r assigning Cat item to int type so in order to get the correct output u hava change code as

```
Cat cat=cats.get(index);
```